# Select first and second of class

Tags: css, sass

My SCSS looks like this:

```
.wrapper {
    .part {
        ...
        &.wheel {
            ... // code goes here
        }
     }
}
```

And my html looks like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="..." class="part wheel"/>
    <img src="..." class="part wheel"/>
</div>
```

How can I select first and second `wheel` using CSS? I want to give them different properties.

Comment: have a look at `:nth-child` selector but beware as it is an element selector (rather than class) so if you have any other elements in between, it won't work

Comment: `&:nth-of-type(1) { ... }` and `&:nth-of-type(2) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

```
.wheel:nth-of-type(1){...}
.wheel:nth-of-type(2){...}
```

or

```
.wheel:nth-child(1){...}
.wheel:nth-child(2){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `nth-of-type`

```
.wrapper {
    .part {
        ...
        &.wheel {
            &:nth-of-type(1) { ... }
            &:nth-of-type(2) { ... }
        }
     }
}
```